# What is in bottom half of BlueScreenView?

Tags: bsod, bluescreenview

Suppose, I opened BSOD in BlueScreenView.

I see screen, divided into two halves. In upper half I see a list of past BSODs.

What I see in the lower half?

Do I see some STACK? If I see topmost red is `ntoskrnel.exe`, does it mean that only this thing had a problem? What about nexts down? Are they callers? Or unrelated parallel processes?

How to see stack?

Comment: Please add a screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: You might use "windbg". The bluescreen might have different causes, like software, driver, hardware, malware. Also the Actioncenter might help.

Comment: is the question now answered? I showed you all option from the button half, so mark it as answer: meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

The `Lower Pane` panel can be configured to show different view:

[image]

1st option shows all loaded drivers:

[image]

2nd option shows only the 2 important drivers used:

[image]

3rd options shows the XP BSOD (shown in first picture), the 4th runs dumpchk.exe and the last on shows a RAW data:

[image]

The best option is the use the XP BSOD dialog.